# Build a template from multiple blocks

Tags: cakephp

Good day everyone! hope you are having a good day.
My challenge today is... Can I have a template (ctp) with nested blocks from separate CTP templates. For instance:

Some form with headers and what not

```
<h1 id-"Something">Testing</h1>
<div class="main section">
   <div class="">
       -Section 1 - this would another ctp (include **section1.ctp**)
       -Section 2 - this would another ctp (include **section2.ctp**)
   </div>
</div>
<footer>something here</footer>
```

Rest of the form

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, everything is neatly documented in the cakephp book

- **Extending Views && Using View Blocks**
- **Elements**

**https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views.html**

the same is for [CakePHP3](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views.html)